# What is the common way to check the check box field in a pdf using iTextsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am filling the data for a fillable pdf using iTextsharp. There are n number of checkboxes in the pdf form. I have set the value for the check boxes using "Yes" or "No". This works fine. But some of the check boxes does not work in this way; instead i need to use 1 or 0 to make it work. So can anyone help me what is the common way to check/uncheck the checkboxes in pdf using iTextSharp?

Thanks in Advance,

Snowwhite

Answer (score 18):

Open chosen PDF and convert it.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileNameIn);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(fileNameOut));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
```

Inspect the form objects Fields > Keys > Results view to find the string value of a Check Box, in my case is was "Check Box1"

```
String[] checkboxstates = form.GetAppearanceStates("Check Box1");
```

Inspect the checkboxstates variable. [0] = value of non checked, [1] = value of checked. Then to make it checked

```
fields.SetField("Check Box1", checkboxstates[1])
```

Comment: I had to change `stamper.getAcroFields();` to `stamper.AcroFields();` but this works great.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the fields can have multiple states and anything greater than the default state (index 0) will be checked.

Comment: Hmm, on my PDF there was only one checkbox state, setting the field value to an empty string cleared it. The one state that `GetAppearenceStates` returned was what I needed, though.

Comment: This was helpful, but I have one small quibble: The last line of the answer should start with "form.SetField" instead of "fields.SetField" based on the name of the variable created earlier in the answer.

Comment: This answer is not accurate, because the order in the AppearanceStates maybe inverted, one should check for the PdfName.OFF value.

Answer (score 7):

you can find in this way:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileNameIn);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(fileNameOut));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

form.setField("Name","Test Name");
form.setField("odot","123456");
form.setField("Consortium","A Testing Co");
form.setField("PName","My Name");
form.setField("date","10/14/03");
form.setField("Box1","true"); //This is the checkbox control
stamper.close();
```

hope this help

Answer (score 3):

There is no "common way".  You need to know the check/uncheck values in order to change them.

There's a similar question I answered where I showed how to find out those values... Ah!

[Get the export value of a checkbox using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491156/get-the-export-value-of-a-checkbox-using-itextsharp/4495482#4495482)

Answer (score 3):

pdfFormFields.SetField("formfieldchkbox", "Yes");
pdfFormFields.SetField("formfieldchkbox", "No");

That should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this

```
stamp.AcroFields.SetField("chk1", "Yes");
stamp.AcroFields.SetField("chk2", "No");
```

Comment: This only works under special circumstances. In general one needs to determine the state names like in [Meir Snyder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107530/1729265).

Answer (score 0):

I find that I can set export value of check box control in PDF file using Adobe Acrobat,
When the export value is set as "anytext" I can check the checkbox using following code:

```
form.setField("Box1","anytext")
```

[Property window of Check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLRwz.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this export value is very important.

```
String pathin = @"D:\Research And Development\ITextSharpPdf\Data\\ACR_Form_Ver_11.pdf";
String pathout = @"D:\Research And Development\ITextSharpPdf\Data\ACR_Form_Ver_11_out.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathin);// formFile);
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(pathout, FileMode.Create)))
        {

            var formFields = stamper.AcroFields;
            //formFields.SetField(<fieldname>, <exportvalue>,<true/false>);
            formFields.SetField("pdfQ1No", "No",true);
            formFields.SetField("pdfAppNo", "234234");
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
        }
```

[image: pdfescapteeditimage]

[image: outputimage]