# Get field value for the check box

Tags: itext

How to find the field value for the check box?

```
<</Rect[263.571 330.311 273.323 338.812]/Subtype/Widget/F 4/P 30 0 R/T(AmountCollect)/DA(/ZaDb 18 Tf 0 g)/FT/Btn/Type/Annot/MK<</CA(8)>>/AP<</D<</COLLECT 148 0 R/Off 149 0 R>>/N<</COLLECT 147 0 R>>>>/AS/Off>>
```

I tried the following. But I am unable to mark the check box. Please help.

```
 testForm.SetField("AmountCollect", "Off");
 testForm.SetField("AmountCollect", "Yes");
 testForm.SetField("AmountCollect", "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string values you're using aren't working, the check box probably uses different names for the appearance state. You can find the possible values of the appearance state using the `GetAppearanceStates` (see the [Buttons](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=154) example), or you can use [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/rups544) to inspect the PDF and search for the names of the appearance states using a GUI.

PS: you can find the C# version of the examples of chapter 8 [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C08).

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Yup you are correct.  Check box uses a custom value "Collect"

Answer (score 0):

testForm.SetField("AmountCollect", "COLLECT"); worked for me.

Reference post :
[Get the export value of a checkbox using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491156/get-the-export-value-of-a-checkbox-using-itextsharp)